# No vanilla JUnit dependency in spring-boot-starter-test?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, gradle, junit

I created a brand new (Gradle, Java Language, Boot 2.2.6, Jar & Java 11) project in start.spring.io (no dependencies specified). I expected to see vanilla JUnit (`junit:junit:x.xx`) dependency in the testing classpath. But do not find it.

Executing `./gradlew dependencies` does not include the vanilla JUnit but only `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter`. Please see the relevant output below.

The default generated test (`DemoApplicationTests.java`) only has an `import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;` instead of `import org.junit.Test`.

What am I missing? The complete build.gradle is included below for easy reference.

---

Relevant portion of `./gradlew dependencies`:

```
\--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test -> 2.2.6.RELEASE
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter:2.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.2.6.RELEASE
     |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot:2.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test-autoconfigure:2.2.6.RELEASE
     |    +--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-test:2.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     |    \--- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-autoconfigure:2.2.6.RELEASE (*)
     +--- com.jayway.jsonpath:json-path:2.4.0
     |    +--- net.minidev:json-smart:2.3
     |    |    \--- net.minidev:accessors-smart:1.2
     |    |         \--- org.ow2.asm:asm:5.0.4
     |    \--- org.slf4j:slf4j-api:1.7.25 -> 1.7.30
     +--- jakarta.xml.bind:jakarta.xml.bind-api:2.3.3
     |    \--- jakarta.activation:jakarta.activation-api:1.2.2
     +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter:5.5.2
     |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2
     |    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |    |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
     |    |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.5.2
     |    |         \--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |    +--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-params:5.5.2
     |    |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |    |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2 (*)
     |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-engine:5.5.2
     |         +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |         +--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-engine:1.5.2
     |         |    +--- org.apiguardian:apiguardian-api:1.1.0
     |         |    +--- org.opentest4j:opentest4j:1.2.0
     |         |    \--- org.junit.platform:junit-platform-commons:1.5.2 (*)
     |         \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.5.2 (*)
     +--- org.mockito:mockito-junit-jupiter:3.1.0
     |    +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0
     |    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy:1.9.10 -> 1.10.8
     |    |    +--- net.bytebuddy:byte-buddy-agent:1.9.10 -> 1.10.8
     |    |    \--- org.objenesis:objenesis:2.6
     |    \--- org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter-api:5.4.2 -> 5.5.2 (*)
     +--- org.assertj:assertj-core:3.13.2
     +--- org.hamcrest:hamcrest:2.1
     +--- org.mockito:mockito-core:3.1.0 (*)
     +--- org.skyscreamer:jsonassert:1.5.0
     |    \--- com.vaadin.external.google:android-json:0.0.20131108.vaadin1
     +--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.5.RELEASE (*)
     +--- org.springframework:spring-test:5.2.5.RELEASE
     |    \--- org.springframework:spring-core:5.2.5.RELEASE (*)
     \--- org.xmlunit:xmlunit-core:2.6.4
```

---

Complete `build.gradle`

```
plugins {
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.2.6.RELEASE'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.9.RELEASE'
    id 'java'
}

group = 'com.example'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '11'

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter'
    testImplementation('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test') {
        exclude group: 'org.junit.vintage', module: 'junit-vintage-engine'
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}
```

Comment: `org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter` **is** JUnit, although in version [5.x](https://junit.org/junit5/). The vanilla `junit:junit` dependency is the older JUnit version [4.x](https://junit.org/junit4/)

Comment: Ahhh...got it. The release notes do say that: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-2.2-Release-Notes#junit-5. Happy to accept this as an answer if posted as one. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`org.junit.jupiter:junit-jupiter` is JUnit, although in version [5.x](https://junit.org/junit5/).

The vanilla `junit:junit` dependency that you seem to expect is the older JUnit version [4.x](https://junit.org/junit4/)